# Getting JSON data from a REST service

Tags: jquery, json, rest

I have a REST service that returns some sample JSON:

```
  public string DoJSONWork()
    {
        return "{\"name\":\"unknown\", \"age\":-1}";
    }
```

I'm trying to consume it from a web page:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://nwcm2012/SMService/SocialMediaWS/DoJSONWork",
            dataType: "json",
            success:
                function (resp) {
                    alert("Server said: " + resp);
                },

            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

But it keeps hitting the error message. No tutorial / example gives me any clue as to what's wrong!

Comment: What **`error message`**?

Comment: I think he means the error alert. Have you tried retrieving the data in the browser? Can you not have your error function return the error code from the server, so we know if it's malformed JSON, or an authorisation error, or whatever?

Comment: it just hits the alert("error") line, so the error message is just "error".

Comment: There's no error on the server. The method returns this JSON: "{\"name\":\"unknown\", \"age\":-1}";

Comment: how do you get the error code returned?

Comment: If you check the request in the network tab of the console what is the exact response code and text?

Comment: hi Rory -  "network tab of the console " - I don't know what you're referring to?

Comment: If I call the method in IE, it prompts to open a file and then shows:

{"DoJSONWorkResult":"{\"name\":\"unknown\", \"age\":-1}"}

Comment: OK - you're talking about dev tools? in network tab the result is 200.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://nwcm2012/SMService/SocialMediaWS/DoJSONWork",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (resp) {
        alert("Server said: " + JSON.stringify(resp));
    }).error(function (err) {
        alert("error: " +JSON.stringify(err));
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck - Its' returning error: [object Object]

Comment: OK - it says error: {readyState: 0, status: 0, statusText: "Error: Access is denied"}

Comment: I've changed to jsonp and now getting this message:

JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 20 in http://nwcm2012/SMService/SocialMediaWS/DoJSONWork?callback=jQuery112208659447333451338_1464176900293&_=1464176900294\n\nSCRIPT1004: Expected ';'

So looks as though I'm now receiving data, but in the wrong format

Comment: Can you host your service?

Comment: It's a self-hosted web service running in a Windows service

Comment: You're going to have to look at what the service requires then.

Answer (score 0):

try your service with  [Sample data provider](http://restipsum.com)